# Why doesn't generate-new-buffer work in M-x?

Tags: functions, m-x

According to the documentation `generate-new-buffer "buffername"` creates a new empty buffer with the given name, yet when I try it in `M-x` the prompt refuses the name and replaces it with "No match". Does it mean it works with only preconfigured names?

At http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_new_empty_buffer.html there is an example where it is used as `(generate-new-buffer "untitled")`, so why doesn't work with `M-x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `generate-new-buffer` function is not an interactive command, and so it cannot be called using `M-x`. Commands are lisp functions that have an `(interactive)` form to define how arguments can be provided interactively. `M-x` can only be used to call such commands.

If you wanted you could write your own command to wrap a function like `generate-new-buffer`:

```
(defun my-generate-new-buffer (name)
  (interactive "s")
  (generate-new-buffer name))
```

But this particular example isn't very useful and there is a built-in command for doing this already: use `switch-to-buffer` (or it's default binding `C-x b`). This will prompt for a buffer name and can be used to create a new named buffer and switch to it.

See the Emacs Lisp manual section [Defining Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html#Defining-Commands) for more about interactive commands.